# How to initialize a vector that's sorted in rust?

Tags: rust, vector

Typically if we declare a vector type and we want it sorted right from the get go we write something like :

```rs
let mut vec = vec![ /* .. unsorted items */ ];
vec.sort();
// vec is now sorted
```

But you might notice the `mut` qualifier making it mutable. Is there a way to have it immutable and sorted right from the start?

Ideally would like `sort()` to consume `self` and return a new vector but I am not too sure about the memory move semantics in question here:

```rs
let vec = vec![ /* .. unsorted items */ ].sort(); 
// vec is sorted and immutable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just [shadow the binding](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/variable_bindings/scope.html):

```rust
let mut vec = vec![ /* .. unsorted items */ ];
vec.sort();
let vec = vec;
```

or do initialization in a block:

```rust
let vec = {
    let mut foo = vec![ /* .. unsorted items */ ];
    foo.sort();
    foo
};
```

Comment: If the pattern comes up multiple times, I'd also consider a utility function `fn sorted<T>(mut v: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a mutable variable immutable later using [variable shadowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/variable_bindings/scope.html).

```rust
let mut vec = vec![ /* .. unsorted items */ ];
vec.sort(); // vec is now sorted

let vec = vec; // from now onward vec is immutable
```